# Re-def vars in Clojure(script)

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to find the idiomatic way to defer the initialization of a var (which I really intend to be immutable).

```
(def foo nil)
...
(defn init []
  ; (def foo (some-function))
  ; (set! foo (some-function)))
```

I know Rich Hickey said [re-defing isn't idiomatic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/znld0ftkbfE/u47Cfe1LDOQJ).  Is `set!` appropriate here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`delay`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/delay):

> Takes a body of expressions and yields a Delay object that will
>   invoke the body only the first time it is forced (with force or deref/@), and
>   will cache the result and return it on all subsequent force
>   calls. See also - realized?

Example usage:

```
(def foo (delay (init-foo))) ;; init-foo is not called until foo is deref'ed

(defn do-something []
  (let [f @foo] ;; init-foo is called the first time this line is executed,
                ;; and the result saved and re-used for each subsequent call.
    ...
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides using delay as Alex states in his answer, set! works just fine because vars are just javascript variables under the hood.

Yous *shouldn't* really directly set! vars like this, but for special cases like this I personally allow myself to (sparingly) do so (ie the data actually is normal immutable Clojure once set up). One example where I do this is to override functions in debug builds:

```
(defn foo [] release code here)
```

Then in a file that is added only to debug builds:

```
(defn debug-foo []
  (.log js/console "foo called"))
(set! foo debug-foo)
```

Comment: I was wondering what practices existed for modifying code in debug builds.  Thank you for sharing that!

Comment: And strange, `set!` works with vars in ClojureScript but not Clojure.

Comment: ```set!``` works in ClojureScript because it is used to mutate javascript variables - "vars" in ClojureScript are not Var's; Clojure Var's don't exist in ClojureScript and also don't support mutation. In Clojure, you don't mutate "variables" - you bind them to names or you use refs/atoms/agents. In ClojureScript ```set!``` mutates the Javascript variable directly. In a way, I guess being able to use ```set!``` like this is an artifact of the ClojureScript implementation, though I don't know if it was planned that way or not.  Hope that makes sense.